# Getting 'Data may be lost' error while opening Excel file generated by JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi

I am using POI 3.7 and Jasper reports 5.6, I'm trying to export an excel report, but it opens with `File error: data may be lost`.

I just added a label and a parameter, tried to preview the report in iReport designer and it works fine, both pdf and xls. This means my jrxml is fine. Not sure why this issue is caused. In many forums it is suggested to use anything higher than poi 3.6, which I have :(

Java code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byos = JasperReportUtil.getInstance().printExcelReport(
                    templateName, beanDS,sourcePath,binPath,inputParams);
jasperRptResponseHandler.handleJasperResponse(
                templateName, byos, "xls", response);
```

Comment: Did you check the version of *POI* used by *JR Engine v 5.6* (in *pom.xml* file)?

Comment: Apache POI 3.7 is pretty ancient - [see the fixes since then in the change log!](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.7) Why not use a more modern version?